# TYPO3 TypoScript Template value dynamic from content element field

Tags: typo3

I want to set the template path dynamic, a redakteur can choose a form in a content element and like the chosen form I want to set the path in cObject.

```
lib.embeddedForm = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.embeddedForm {
    template = TEXT
    template {
        value = <formvh:render persistenceIdentifier="EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/form/Forms/form.form.yaml" />
    }
```

This is what I have. Instead of form.form.yaml I want a dynamic version like

```
template {
        value = <formvh:render persistenceIdentifier="EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/form/Forms/{field:selectForm}.form.yaml" />
```

Is this possible? And how can I do this?

Thanks for any idea.
Ah actual TYPO3 10.4.31
}

Comment: In general something like that is indeed possible, but what is your question in detail?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using a `FLUIDTEMPLATE` instead of `TEXT`. But that's very atypically... What's the reason you want that to do?

Typically, you would configure a chain of paths für Layouts/Templates/Partials in the forms YAML:

```
prototypes:
  standard:
    formElementsDefinition:
      Form:
        renderingOptions:
          templateRootPaths:
            100: 'EXT:my_site_package/Resources/Private/Frontend/Templates/'
            110: 'EXT:my_site_package/Resources/Private/Frontend/SpecialForm/Templates/'
          partialRootPaths:
            100: 'EXT:my_site_package/Resources/Private/Frontend/Partials/'
            110: 'EXT:my_site_package/Resources/Private/Frontend/Partials/'
          layoutRootPaths:
            100: 'EXT:my_site_package/Resources/Private/Frontend/Layouts/'
```

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/FrontendRendering/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

IMO this can be achieved by rendering the from through FLUIDTEMPLATE as mentioned in the Documentation.

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/FrontendRendering/Index.html#render-through-fluidtemplate-without-controller

```
tt_content.custom_content_element = COA_INT
tt_content.custom_content_element {
    10 = < lib.stdheader
    20 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    20 {
        file = EXT:my_site_package/Resources/Private/Templates/CustomContentElement.html
        settings {
            persistenceIdentifier = EXT:my_site_package/Resources/Private/Forms/MyForm.yaml
        }
        extbase.pluginName = Formframework
        extbase.controllerExtensionName = Form
        extbase.controllerName = FormFrontend
        extbase.controllerActionName = perform
    }
}
```

Maybe you can provide the layout option for this content element, when switching the layout option you can change the from YAML as well.

PS: Haven't done this and this is just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in the TypoScript FLUIDTEMPLATE context, you can always use `stdWrap` methods to create dynamic values based on DB fields.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html

Your template is already generated as a TEXT cObject, so you can use `field`, `data`, `wrap` and/or `dataWrap` to do so:

```
lib.embeddedForm = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.embeddedForm {
  template = TEXT
  template {
    dataWrap = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/form/Forms/{field:selectForm}.form.yaml
  }
}
```